# Access tweepy search object

Tags: python, api, tweepy

Im using django and want to use the tweepy api just to search tweets matching the users input.

I am able to get 'text' from the objects but that is all.

The object as you know its quite large and im finding difficult selecting what I need out of it.

I currently just need screen name and name

Is there a way I can see the object formatted better?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import tweepy
import json

# Create your views here.
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


def index(requests):
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                               query="xbox",
                               q="{xbox}",
                               count=1,
                               result_type="recent",
                               include_entities=True,
                               lang="en").items():
        print(tweet.text)

        twitter_data = {
            'tweet': tweet.text,
            # 'screen_name': tweet['user_mentions'][0]
        }

    context = {'twitter_data': twitter_data}
    return render(requests, 'twitter/twitter.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen name to the user who posted the tweet use:

```
# user name
tweet.user.name

# user screen name
tweet.user.screen_name
```